# Can't uninstall manually installed python 2.7.5

Tags: python, uninstall

I manually installed python 2.7.5 using checkinstall.  I downloaded and extracted the source tarball from python.org in /usr/local/src, then ran these commands

```
./configure
sudo make
sudo checkinstall
```

I wanted to upgrade from 2.7.4 to 2.7.5, I probably could have used apt-get to just install the next version, but now I want to uninstall it, I went to the ubuntu software center and tried to remove it, but it tells me that I need to remove all these other programs that depend on python even though I already have the python version that came with my installation.  I'm not really sure how to uninstall it.

apt-cache policy python python2.7 outputs:

```
python:
  Installed: 2.7.5-1
  Candidate: 2.7.5-1
  Version table:
 *** 2.7.5-1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.7.4-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main amd64 Packages
python2.7:
  Installed: 2.7.4-2ubuntu3
  Candidate: 2.7.4-2ubuntu3
  Version table:
 *** 2.7.4-2ubuntu3 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

in `/usr/local/src/Python2.7.5`, there is a deb package called `python_2.7.5-1_amd64.deb`.

Comment: Did you create packages (`.deb`) using checkinstall - e.g. `sudo checkinstall make install_package`? Or did you install it directly?

Comment: I downloaded and extracted the source tarball from python.org in /usr/local/src, ran `./configure` then `sudo make` and `sudo checkinstall`.  I'm not sure what you mean by if I created packages or installed it directly (sorry, I'm new to ubuntu, I got it yesterday).

Comment: First of all, please **edit** your question to include new information - it's how this site works. Secondly, also explain *why* you did this in the first place as Ubuntu has Python 2.7 perfectly fine in the repositories for you. I.e. What were you trying to accomplish? Thirdly, since Python is a really fundamental piece of software for Ubuntu, you really cannot uninstall it and install a new version afterwards - you'll need to make sure there's a working Python installation at all times.

Comment: I have two versions of python 2.7.x on my system, one that I manually installed in /usr/local/bin and the one that came installed in /usr/bin

Comment: (I am just reading up on checkinstall by the way.) As far as I understand it, it will create `.deb` packages which you can install and remove. Are you sure this is the full sequence of events as to how you got Python in `/usr/local`? Do you still have the directory there and the `.deb` packages? Please provide a list of them and the output of `apt-cache policy python python2.7`

Comment: doesnt the install go: ./configure make sudo make install  ? boy if i rea teh readme and see that it is..

Comment: straight out of the read me:If you don't read instructions
------------------------------

Congratulations on getting this far. :-)

To start building right away (on UNIX): type "./configure" in the
current directory and when it finishes, type "make".  This creates an
executable "./python"; to install in /usr/local, first do "su root"
and then "make install".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you were very lucky to have used `checkinstall`! Instead of installing it bluntly by overwriting/moving files it created a package which got installed. This makes the package management aware of the installation and how to undo it. So, this means you can tell APT that you now want to install the other version:

Run

```
sudo apt-get install python=2.7.4-0ubuntu1
```

to revert to the regular Ubuntu packaged version. Python 2.7.5 will probably only be available in Saucy, not in the current stable releases.

This is not the same as removing and reinstalling, as in this case it gets downgraded taking care a single version of Ubuntu is installed at all times.

Comment: sudo apt-get install python=2.7.4-0ubuntu1

Comment: @VaidAbhishek What about it?

Comment: I installed it manually. But how do I install modules to new version instead of default build

Comment: @VaidAbhishek If you have a NEW question, ask a new one by clicking the "Ask Question" button at the top of the page. Comments are not meant for new issues/questions not relevant the the OP.

Comment: Why is 2.7.5 still unavailable in 12.04? 2.7.3 has a bad 64bit cPickle bug :(

Comment: @Will Because you will never receive newer versions for an Ubuntu release. That's how Ubuntu development/releasing works; they're called freezes. Bugs fixed in more recent versions will get backported if serious enough. Please report the bug you found using `apport-bug python2.7` (or check if there's a bug report already and mark yourself as affected). See also: [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](http://askubuntu.com/q/151283/88802)